# SharpSVN: What does "Is Last Invocation Canceled" mean?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I'm using SharpSVN 1.6 with .Net 3.5.
I saw the property `IsLastInvocationCanceled` in a few SvnArgs (UpdateArgs, CommitArgs etc.), and I couldn't find a documentation on it.

Can someone please tell me what does it mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `ThrowOnWarning` and/or `ThrowOnError` disabled, on your next call `IsLastInvocationCanceled` will be true if a warning or error (respectively) occurred on your last invocation.

Comment: The same goes for `ThrowOnCancel`, but then of course you need to manually cancel a request.

Answer (score 0):

After checking, the intended behavior is that `IsLastInvocationCanceled` is *only* true when the `Cancel` property on the EventArgs is set (to cancel the current operation), like so:

```
SvnUpdateArgs ua = new SvnUpdateArgs();
client.List(url, ua, delegate(object sender, SvnUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
});

Assert.That(ua.IsLastInvocationCanceled);
```